# Is there a way to disable search of specific fields in advance search while still allowing their availability in the filterToolbar in JqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using the free jqGrid.  In it I am employing the filterToolbar for searching filtering data in all fields of the grid and sub-grid as a grid, except the *date fields* where I am unable to employ a date range picker (to-date still working on that).  In the mean time, I would like to use the advanced search to search the date fields only.

Is there a way or a setting that I have yet to be able to uncover where I can disable specific columns/fields from the advanced search WITHOUT disabling them from the filterToolbar?

(Don't know if this matters - but all of the sorting/filtering and paging is being done client side once the data hits...loadonce: true.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `columns` searching option to customize, which is in general the copy of elements (columns) from `colModel`. Using `columns` option one can change the order of columns. One can include column, which have `search: false` property or one can include any property from `additionalProperties`, which can be used as replacement of hidden columns.

I prepared [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/searchSpecificColumns.htm), which demonstrates the implementation. The demo uses input data which looks like

```
{ id: "50",  invdate: "2015-10-31", name: "test5",  note: "note5",
  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" }
```

I defined `colModel` with columns which corresponds all the input properties with exception `id` used to assign rowids. I included in the column `tax` the property `search: false` to exclude it from searching/filtering by default. Additionally I defined `additionalProperties` as

```
additionalProperties: [
    { name: "id", sorttype: "integer" }
]
```

It allows to sort and to search by the property `id`. Items of `additionalProperties` can be in one from the two forms: as strings like `"id"` or like objects with the same format like `colModel`. The option `additionalProperties` is very practical in case of usage `loadonce: true` option. It allows to include in the local data any additional properties from input data (the data returned from the server). The values of the properties can have *any type*. For example you can return pron the server any helper data like subgrid data, values of composed keys and so on. After usage of `additionalProperties: ["id"]` or better the above value `additionalProperties: [ { name: "id", sorttype: "integer" }]` we will be able to sort by id (by usage `sortname: "id"`) or searching by `id`.

To customize the searching dialog I used searching option

```
columns: [
    { name: "closed", label: "Closed",
        stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;true:Yes;false:No" } },
    { name: "id", label: "Id", sorttype: "integer",
        searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"] }},
    { name: "name", label: "Client name",
        searchoptions: { sopt: ["cn", "bw", "ew", "eq", "bn", "nc", "en"] } },
    { name: "amount", label: "Amount", sorttype: "integer",
        searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"] } },
    { name: "tax", formatter: "integer", sorttype: "integer",
        searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"] } },
    { name: "ship_via", label: "Shipped via",
        stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:IN" } },
    { name: "note" }
]
```

which includes some columns from `colModel`. I set `label` to specify custom names of searching fields. You can see that the column `invdate` in not included, but non-searchable column `tax` and additional property `id` are included.

The properties, which will be used currently in `columns` items are: `name`, `label`, `stype`, `searchoptions`, `sorttype`. `formatter` and `formatoptions` will be used only in case of `sorttype: "date"` or `sorttype: "datetime"` and  `formatter: "date"`. In the case `srcformat` and `newformat` of `formatoptions` will be used during searching/filtering. Because we don't included date column in `columns`, the `formatter` and `formatoptions` will be not needed in `columns`.

You can test the demo to see that the searching dialog works like expected. The Searching Dialog looks like on the picture below

[image]

Comment: This worked like a charm!  Had not used additionalProperties. Perfect Oleg, Thank you!

Comment: @gal66stang: I introduced `additionalProperties` based on my previous experience. I recommend you to take a look in the possibility. The simplest usage is very easy: you extend any item of data with additional information and include the names of the properties in  `additionalProperties` array. After that the properties will be saved locally. There are accessible in custom formatter, `cellattr`, `rowattr` and in `data`  parameter of the grid. You use `.getLocalRow(rowid)` to get the item of data from local `data` by rowid. The item will contains all columns data and `additionalProperties`.

Comment: it seems very useful and powerful within the application.   I will most certainly incorporate it.  It looks like it will absolutely meet the requirement that I have currently.  Thank you so much for all of your work on this application and feedback on this and other sites.  It has been instrumental in my learning of the grid.

Comment: @gal66stang: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you.